# Loading splash screen freezes unless I use nomodeset

Tags: boot, drivers, xorg, 18.04, display-resolution

I recently upgraded to 18.04 and have been struggling with start up being **stuck on the splash screen**.

I manage to get past the splash screen stalling by adding nomodeset to the boot cmdline. But the max resolution I can then use is 1024x768 where as if I boot from the LiveCD and 'try Ubuntu' i can get to 1920x1080.

There have been quite a few similar questions posed before on this forum and I think **I've tried most of the suggested solutions but nothing is working**

- I'm using Intel 82Q35 Express Integrated Graphic Controller (rev 02). And have updated the xorg.conf to disable uxa
- Added xorg.conf with X -configure everywhere /etc, /etc/X11, /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
- Played around with all the apci,lapci stuff on boot
- Updated to the latest version of xserver-xorg-video-intel

And all to no avail. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What version did you upgrade from and was it working without problems then?

Comment: When you get to the normal splash screen can you enter `ctrl`+`alt`+`f2`?

Comment: It was a really old install 14.something i believe. It was running fine but I didn't do the install so don't know if there was some config setting that had been changed to make it run.

Comment: @JohnSnow When the splash screen stalls the mouse pointer appears and is completely unresponsive as well as the keyboard. So ctrl alt f2 doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It might have something to do with Wayland. I didn't find a solution, but a workaround:

- Boot to the desktop by using 'nomodeset' option in GRUB, or selecting recovery mode in GRUB. Hold Shift early in the boot process if necessary
- Log out
- Choose an Xorg-based option to log in with. On future boots, it should boot the last-booted option by default.